# Imagick install error undefined symbol: MagickGetImageBluePrimary

Tags: php, module, imagick

How goes it folks, I've been trying to install imagick on a Centos server with absolutely no luck.

ImageMagick is running fine. MagickWand is installed and the module compiles with no problem.

```
# which MagickWand
/usr/local/bin/MagickWand
# MagickWand --version
6.7.6 Q16 
# which convert
/usr/local/bin/convert
# convert -v
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.6-8 2012-05-03 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP    
[imagick]# make install
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php/modules/
Installing header files:          /usr/include/php/
# php -m | grep imagick
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library'/usr/lib/php/modules/imagick.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/imagick.so: undefined symbol: MagickGetImageBluePrimary in Unknown on line 0
```

Is anybody familiar with this error?...Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error. the problem occurs for the imagick imagick module version-3.0.1. Installing imagick-2.3.0 version works correctly